# Perforce - getting email on every checkin

Tags: version-control, perforce

Is there a way to get Perforce to send you an email on every check to a particular depository?

Comment: Are you asking how to configure the perforce server to provide this functionality, or are you just asking as an end user? If the latter Jeff's answer should be sufficient, assuming your admin has setup the review daemon.

Comment: I was asking for the later. And, yup, Jeff's answer works for me. Brian's answer is also good to know.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes. Type "p4 user" to see your user configuration and then under "Reviews:" put the filespec of the area in depot where you'd like to get notified on a check-in, as in:

```
Reviews:
    //depot/myproject/...
```

See [this section](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_user.html#p4_user.usage) of the P4 command reference for more info.

Comment: What if you want to mail an email list, rather than a particular user?

Comment: I suppose you could create a user that represented the list. I'm not sure of a more efficient way

Answer (score 20):

In p4v (visual client)

1. `Connection` -> `Edit Current User`
2. Enter the path to your repository under `Reviews`

This is correct for OSX & Windows.

Comment: Thanks. Can never remember where to find this feature.

Answer (score 8):

You want to install the Perforce Review Daemon script on your server. What it does is periodically poll the server for new changelists and sends an e-mail **ONLY** to the people interested in them. The script is maintained by Perforce and you can get help from the tech support to setup it.

You can download it from the Perforce website from the support site (towards the bottom of the page).

Perforce Support Site: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/loadsupp.html
Direct Link to Script: http://public.perforce.com/public/perforce/utils/reviewd/p4review.py

Once you have it installed you register your that your interested in changinglists by adding the filespec to your user account.

Comment: Is it possible to send the email before committing the changelist, just for review? Via a script of batch file?

Comment: You could write a pre commit hook; I never done that. Also, I've moved on from wanting emails for every commit. I now recommend the pull request work flow to all our clients.

Answer (score 4):

In the perforce visual client (P4V), go to **Connection** and **Edit current User**
Under the user dialog box, go to the **reviews** tab.
Select and deselect the different trees of the "depot"

Answer (score 1):

As an admin you can use

```
p4 triggers
```

to setup scripts that are executed when various actions are performed (ie: on check in of a changelist).  I've used it to send an email to a distribution list that all of the developers were part of so that they were aware of who was checking in what and when.