# enabling perforce notification only on certain types of files

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588264/perforce-getting-email-on-every-checkin) where someone said how to enable p4 server to email me on changelist submisions. However, is there a way to enable notifications for any file with a *.js extension, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [installing the review daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588264/perforce-getting-email-on-every-checkin), set the "Reviews:" section of your user spec to "Reviews: //....js", to indicate that you wish to review only those changes which touched files ending in .js.