# Automatic checkout in Perforce

Tags: perforce, vcs-checkout

I want to know if there is an in built functionality in Perforce which allows us to automatically check out code. I have multiple servers and I would like to have an option where, when I modify a script in one of the servers and check it into perforce, it automatically checks out the script out to the other servers.

Comment: By 'check out' on the other servers, do you mean 'get latest'?

Comment: Yes. Get latest automatically to the local workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three possible approaches here, *subscription* and *polling* and *triggers*.

**Subscription**

In this approach, you get Perforce to notify you when there's a change, and respond accordingly. However, the only notification you can get from Perforce is an email sent to a user account's email address. So you could configure the servers to respond to the email by running a `p4 sync` command. Microsoft Outlook Rules and Alerts (for example) can be configured to do this quite easily. This answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588264/perforce-getting-email-on-every-checkin) and this documentation [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v/edit_user.html) shows you how to configure these email alerts.

**Polling**

In this approach, you simply write a short program (batch script, executable, whatever...) that runs constantly on your servers. It just sleeps most of the time, but wakes up and calls `p4 sync` every few minutes on the area of the depot you're interested in. This approach is simple, and doesn't involve any other third party applications. If you're using Windows, running as a service would be ideal, because it would then be able to start up automatically with the server, as well as allow you to 'start' and 'stop' it as required.

I'd say polling is probably your best bet here.

**EDIT**

**Triggers**

From @Matt's comment, it's worth considering a third option, that of triggers, which are documented [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html).

Comment: This is very helpful. Thank you ! I will try out the polling option.

Comment: I would recommend using a trigger. You can have a script run right after submit, propagating the changes to the other servers. No polling and it will be fired immediately after submit. http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html

Comment: True - depends on how the other servers are set up, but definitely another option to consider.

Comment: @Matt: Updated my answer to include this option. Thanks!